# Finding the idAttribute of a collection's model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the context of a Collection, I want to retrive a model instance based on some object containing model data, but I don't want to hard code the idAttribute.

Backbone makes things easy when you already have a model instance, you can just access its `.id` property and it sorts things out, but I can't seem to find a way of going the other way, short of creating a instance of a model just to get at its `idAttribute`.

For example:

```js
var Cat = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    age: null
  },

  idAttribute: 'name'
});

var PushCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    coll = this;
    somePushConnection.on('deleted', function (deleted) {
      _.each(deleted, function (obj) {
        // obj being something like: {name: 'mittens', age: 302}
        var model = coll.get(obj[coll.model.idAttribute]); // Can't do this!
        if (model) { model.destroy(); }
      });
    });
  }
});

var Cats = PushCollection.extend({
  model: Cat
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access it via the model's prototype:

```
Model.prototype.idAttribute
```

Or in your sample code

```
var model = coll.get(obj[coll.model.prototype.idAttribute]);
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Would be nice if you could give a collection's `get` method an arbitrary object and have it pluck out the relevant id attribute to look up.

Comment: @Acorn, nothing's stopping you from adding the functionality to the `Backbone.Collection` yourself: `Backbone.Collection.prototype.findByObject = function(obj) { return this.get(obj[this.model.prototype.idAttribute]); }` (with appropriate nullity checks added, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but couldn't you use the `Collection.where()` method?

From the Backbone documentation:

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models
>   in a collection that match the passed attributes. Useful for simple
>   cases of filter.
>
> ```
> var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
>   {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
>   {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
>   {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
>   {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
> ]);
>
> var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
>
> alert(musketeers.length);
> ```

So, in your sample code:

```
var PushCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    coll = this;
    somePushConnection.on('deleted', function (deleted) {
      _.each(deleted, function (obj) {
        // obj being something like: {name: 'mittens', age: 302}
        var model = coll.where(obj);
        if (model) { model.destroy(); }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That would only work if the object received from the server had attributes identical to the model in the collection on the client. If for example you were receiving updates via the push connection, the attribute values would differ. That's why retrieval by id is necessary.